Calculating a list of voxels within multiple overlapping Axis-Aligned-Bounding-Boxes, without looping over the same space
I have a method that returns a list of voxel coordinates within an AABB. Let's say a voxel is 1x1x1 cm, and a bounding box is 2x2x2, then it will return 8 voxels by looping over the dimensions of the bounding box, a triple-nested for-loop.
Now I have a situation where I have list of these bounding-boxes, all the same size, and most of them are overlapping each other. Is there an algorithm that can efficiently gather a list of voxels within multiple bounding-boxes, without looping over the same space twice?
We could ofcourse, create an std::unordered_set that would prevent duplicates. But you would still loop over the same space very often if the bounding boxes are all in very close proximity to each other, which seems redundant performance wise.
Image representing the issue in 2D
I'm very curious if such an algorithm already exists, or if someone very smart could come up with one.
Simple solution when you have only two bounding-boxes:
If there are only two bounding boxes, then a simple solution is to first loop over 1 of the bounds, then for the second bounds you would check if it overlaps the first, and do a 'boolean cut' if there is any. The remainder of this cut is what does not overlap the first bounds which you can loop over.
When you have more then two bounding-boxes is where it starts to slow down exponentially, because for each box you need to check all other boxes for any overlap.

Just use an unordered set of voxels and add all the voxels to it then loop over the set, it's O(n), you could use a flat unordered set from boost to speed it up, calculating cuts would be a lot slower O(n!), also you can use spatial partitioning to reduce the size of each set, just keep dividing the space until each set is like a few KBs, and as the size of each partition is always constant you can just allocate the sets from a pool.

Yes BSP tree can be used to divide the space. One BSP tree for each bounding box. Maintain a list of BSPs for each bounding box. When constructing a new bounding box, query all other BSPs to see if a given region is already present, if yes, then skip adding that region. Note, that I have never used BSP, just have an idea of what it may do. So do your research.
